# how to increment or dectement number in react-icon when click on bookmark is present on the listingcard

Tags: reactjs

How to increment/decrement the likes and dislikes in react icon which is on the topbar when ckick on book mark in listing cards in reactjs project.

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the value of likes in useState hook:

```
const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = useState(0)
```

then after clicking on bookmark increase the value:

```
<BookmarkIcon onClick={(likeCount)=>setLikeCount(likeCount += 1)} />
```

To show like count in your topbar just use likeCount value with jsx:

```
{likeCount}
```